# Why inplace Tensor methods are const in Torch C++ API?

Tags: c++, libtorch

I see that many inplace Tensor operations like `mul_` and `div_` are const in PyTorch C++ frontend:

```
Tensor &mul_(Scalar other) const
```

It seems to be strange since inplace operations are supposed to modify the tensor data, right? Does anyone know what is the rationale behind making them const?

I've found some [discussions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/17021) on github, but it looks like the title contradicts what is written below:

> 'const Tensor' doesn't provide const safety ... Therefore, these methods should be non-const

Comment: The `Tensor` type is really a smart pointer to real tensor data. The `const` modifies constness of the pointer, not of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As underlined by the comment and by [this thread](https://github.com/zdevito/ATen/issues/27), this `const` is disingenuous because it applies to the pointer to the underlying `TensorImpl`, not to the data itself. This is just for compiling optimization and carry no real semantics here. This is similar to the difference between `const int*`(pointer to const int) and `int* const`(const pointer to int).

Const (resp. non-const) functions in torch are easily recognized with the absence (resp. presence) of a final underscore in the function name.